# get texts from array at indexes where 2D tensor's values are above or equal to thresholds in tensorflow2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have tensorflow tensor with probabilites like this:

```
>>> valid_4_preds
array([[0.9817431 , 0.01259811, 0.50729334, 0.00053732, 0.6966804 ,
        0.00488825],
       [0.9851129 , 0.01246135, 0.38177294, 0.00378728, 0.8398497 ,
        0.68413687],
       [0.00061161, 0.00005008, 0.00017785, 0.0000152 , 0.00017121,
        0.00002404],
       [0.9991425 , 0.23962161, 0.98579687, 0.01727398, 0.9354003 ,
        0.3325037 ]], dtype=float32)
```

I now need to map the above probabilties with different thresholds to `classes`(or a tensor with texts) and get them.

```
>>> # printing classes
>>> classes
<tf.Tensor: shape=(6,), dtype=string, numpy=
array([b'class_1', b'class_2', b'class_3', b'class_4', b'class_5',
       b'class_6'], dtype=object)>
>>> # converting to bools
>>> true_falses = tf.math.greater_equal(valid_4_preds, tf.constant([0.5, 0.40, 0.20, 0.80, 0.5, 0.4]))
>>> true_falses
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 6), dtype=bool, numpy=
array([[ True, False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True, False]])>
```

now, I am trying to get the texts at indices where `true_falses` has `True`s(this is my expected output), like this:

```
>>> <some-tensorflow-operations>
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 6), dtype=bool, numpy=
array([['class_1', 'class_3', 'class_5'],
       ['class_1', 'class_3', 'class_5', 'class_6'],
       [],
       ['class_1', 'class_3', 'class_5']])>
```

Here's what I have tried:

1. `tf.boolean_mask` seems to solve the purpose, but the `mask` it takes in, strictly has to be 1D array.
2. `tf.where` can be used to get the indexes, output of which after reshaping to single dimension can be passed to `tf.gather` to get the respective classes like this:

```
>>> tf.gather(classes, tf.reshape(tf.where(true_falses[0] == True), shape=(-1,)))
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=string, numpy=array([b'class_1', b'class_3', b'class_5'], dtype=object)>
```

But, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this on 2D arrays.

this logic will go in a signature for serving via tensorflow-serving, so operations strictly only needs to be of tensorflow. How do I do this on 2D tensors or arrays? more efficient and quicker operations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tf.ragged.boolean_mask`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ragged/boolean_mask)?

```py
import tensorflow as tf

classes = tf.constant([b'class_1', b'class_2', b'class_3', b'class_4', b'class_5', b'class_6'])
true_falses = tf.constant([
    [ True, False,  True, False,  True, False],
    [ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True],
    [False, False, False, False, False, False],
    [ True, False,  True, False,  True, False]]
)

tf.ragged.boolean_mask(
    data=tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(classes, 0), [tf.shape(true_falses)[0], 1]),
    mask=true_falses
)
# <tf.RaggedTensor [[b'class_1', b'class_3', b'class_5'], [b'class_1', b'class_3', b'class_5', b'class_6'], [], [b'class_1', b'class_3', b'class_5']]>
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. I didn't know about ragged submodule. do you know if ragged-tensors can be returned via tensorflow-serving?

Comment: I do not know about tensorflow-serving. Anyway ragged tensors can be easily converted to standard flat tensor tuples with values and lengths. Huge ragged tensor, however, may work unstable.